# Prism Region overlay

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism, mef

I have a silverlight application made with prism. I have a top region where the user can define some information to search, I have another region which is the workspace region who display the data in a datagrid. 
I would like to add another region on top of the workspace region (like a modal dialog box but a user control that i've defined) which will display the current detail of the selected line when the user double click on the datagrid.
What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps were simple enough for me

1) Create a Region for the overlay in the shell whose visibility is bound to a property in the shell view model

2) Create a **PubSubEvent** of bool (Or **CompositePresentationEvent** according to PRISM version you are using) which will show or hide the overlay region

3) Make the shell view model subscribe to the event and updates the overlay visibility property depending on the bool value

4) On mouse double click on a row publish the event and navigate the view in the overlay region

Comment: It's what I've done, 2 region in the workspace region and the viewmodel of this workspace region suscribe to the event to show detail and display or not the overlay region.

Answer (score 0):

This article details how to use **UserInteractions** to create a dialog window

While the link references WPF, I have seen samples using a similar pattern with ChildWindows in Silverlight.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=PandP.40).aspx#UserInteractionPatterns